# How to select text inside an HTML element, based on content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, find

I want to find how many products are in a list or array inside a website. The one I want to it's called `Course` which is text inside the `<strong >` element.

I can select them all but how can I filter just the ones with the word COURSE I'm using development tools inside my browser.

Here is the code:

I use a selector for the class `var e = document.querySelectorAll('.card-type');`

```
`[<strong class=​"card-type">​Workshop​</strong>​, 
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Course​</strong>​, 
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Workshop​</strong>​,
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Course​</strong>​,
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Workshop​</strong>​, 
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Workshop​</strong>​,
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Workshop​</strong>​,
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Workshop​</strong>​,
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Course​</strong>​, 
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Workshop​</strong>​,
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Course​</strong>​,
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Course​</strong>​, 
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Course​</strong>​,
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Course​</strong>​,
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Course​</strong>​,
 <strong class=​"card-type">​Course​</strong>​ ​]`
```

Comment: convert to array, filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter your list with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
let courses = e.filter(item => item.textContent === "Course");
```

This is using `let` and `fat arrow syntax` aka a lambda which are ES6 syntax. If you want ES5 JavaScript, simply use `var` and a normal anonymous function.

```
var courses = e.filter(function(item) {
    return item.textContent === "Course";
});
```

Edit: Kevin B spotted that my function  will be undefined and he his right. That is because `e` is a `NodeList` and not an array. We have to convert it! There are multiple ways to convert a NodeList to an array. The easiest being `splice`. Or you can get fancy and use `spread` syntax `[...e].filter` or `Array.from()` as well, which are both also ES6 features.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did step by step answer:

1. Select the elements I want to:
   `var e = document.querySelectorAll('.card-type');`
2. Make that variable into an Array:
    `const f = Array.apply(null, e);`
3. Now filter with the **New Array**:
   `let courses = f.filter(item => item.textContent === 'Courses');`

And the **2 option** if you don't want to convert to an ARRAY just loop NodeList.

```js
let course = document.querySelectorAll('.card-type');
```

With the old good **For Loop**

```
for(let i = 0; i < course.length; i++) {
   console.log(course.item(i).innerText)
}
```

And **IF** statement for get the COURSE word ONLY

```js
for (let i =0; i < course.length; i++) {
     if(course.item(i).innerHTML == "Course") 
     {
        console.log(course.item(i));
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using jquery, you can do it in only a few lines, using [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) and [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

```
$('.card-type').each(function(el, i) {
  var text = $(el).text();
    if (text == "Course") {
       console.log("found it");
    }
});
```

Basically you iterate through all the elements of the list, then check each one for the right content, and do something else with that.

You can use other things like filtering down, but it really all depends on what you're looking to do with the elements.